# batch script does not work properly in case of special character `!`?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have tried the below batch script which behaves differently in case of special character `!`.

Script `test.bat`:

```
@ECHO OFF 
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion 
set "psCommand=powershell -Command "$pword = read-host 'Enter Password' -AsSecureString; ^
    $BSTR=System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal::SecureStringToBSTR($pword);
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%G in (%psCommand%) do set password=%%G echo !password!
```

Output:

> ```
> C:\Users\abc>test.bat
> Enter Password: *********
> Hello123
> ```

Here I have entered `Hello!123` but in the output `!` is missing.

Comment: try `echo %password%`

Comment: If you set EnableDelayedExpansion then ! is a variable name. This is basic stuff.

Answer (score 3):

When delayed variable expansion is enabled, the exclamation mark is used to enclose variables to read/expand. Since delayed expansion is done after expanding `for` variables, any `!` is consumed by the delayed expansion feature. To overcome this, you need to disable delayed expansion during expansion of a `for` variable and enable it only where you actually need it, like this:

```
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
rem Some code...
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%G in (%psCommand%) do (
    set password=%%G
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    echo(!password!
    endlocal
)
endlocal
```

Note that any changes you make to a variable are lost after the `endlocal` command.

Comment: @ECHO OFF 
set "psCommand=powershell -Command "$pword = read-host 'Enter omc password:' -AsSecureString ; ^
      $BSTR=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pword); ^
            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)""
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%G in (`%psCommand%`) do set password=%%G
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    echo !password!
    endlocal

Comment: could you please explain what is the need of "(" in  echo(!password!

Comment: Supposing `!password!` is empty, `echo !password!` would return something like `ECHO is on.`; the `(` avoids that, so an empty line is returned; there is also the commonly used technique to write `echo.!progress!` which you might already have seen, but this fails if a file `echo.` exists in the current directory; `echo(` is the only safe variant to avoid the aforementioned message...

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like this for setting a password and you can set of course a password like `Hello!123`

```
@echo off
Title %~n0 by Hackoo 2016
Mode 50,5 & Color 0E
:CreatePassword
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
Call :InputPassword "Please choose your password" pass1
Call :InputPassword "Please confirm your password" pass2
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
If !pass1!==!pass2! ( Goto:Good ) Else ( Goto:Bad )
::***********************************
:InputPassword
Cls
echo.
echo.
set "psCommand=powershell -Command "$pword = read-host '%1' -AsSecureString ; ^
    $BSTR=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pword); ^
      [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)""
        for /f "usebackq delims=" %%p in (`%psCommand%`) do set %2=%%p
Goto :eof
::***********************************        
:Good
Cls
echo.
echo.
Call :Color 0B "                  Good password  " 1  
TimeOut /T 2 /NoBreak>nul
Call :Write_Info
Call :Collect_Info
echo Your password stored as : "!SavedPass!" without quotes
pause
Goto :Eof
::***********************************
:Bad
Cls
echo.
echo.
Call :Color 0C "            Wrong password try again " 1                
TimeOut /T 2 /NoBreak>nul
Goto :CreatePassword
::***********************************
:Color
for /F "delims=." %%a in ('"prompt $H. & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do set "BS=%%a"
set nL=%3
if not defined nL echo Requires third argument & Pause > nul & goto :Eof
if %3 == 0 (
    <nul set /p ".=%BS%">%2 & Findstr /V /A:%1 /R "^$" %2 nul & Del %2 2>&1
    goto :Eof
) else if %3 == 1 (
    echo %BS%>%2 & Findstr /V /A:%1 /R "^$" %2 nul & Del %2 2>&1
    goto :Eof
)
::***********************************
:Write_Info
(echo !Pass2!)>\\?\"%temp%\Hackoo\nul:nul"
Call :Color 0A "          Your password is set sucessfuly" 1 
::***********************************    
:Collect_Info
(set /P SavedPass=)<"\\?\%temp%\Hackoo\nul:nul"
goto :eof
::***********************************
```